# How to filter the Mongoose Arrays of SchemaTypes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a two Mongoose collection "File" and "FileShare".The schema details as below

```
var FileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: { type: String},
shares: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "FileShare" } ]});


var FileShareSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: Number,
user: { type: String }});
```

**Sample Data for File Collection**

```
name                    shares   
================================
 Document1.txt          [1,2]
 Document2.txt          [1]
 Document3.txt          [2]
 Document4.txt          []
```

Sample Data for FileShare Collection

```
_id     user
========================
1       John
2       Raj
```

I want write a query to get the list files which are shared with user. And also need to handle paging using query.

**Expexted Result**

> For User John should get Document1.txt,Document2.txt
>   and User Raj should get Document1.txt,Document3.txt

```
File.find({})
    .populate('FileShare')
    .sort({'_id': 1})   
    .skip(0).limit(25)
    .exec(function (err, files) {
        res.send(files);
    });
```

Please let me know is there any way to get this result using mongoose query.

Comment: You need to use `$lookup` aggregation here... Let us know your mongodb and mongoose version...

Comment: we are using mongoose version using 5.1.0 and mongodb 3.1.1.

Comment: You have to upgrade your mongodb version to use `$lookup` aggregation

Comment: Then we need to use mongodb query insted of mongoose query.Please confirm

Comment: In my aspects both are having same queries... Not sure what difference you think between them

Comment: we will not able to use populate method.Thank you for your suggestion.